# Mock AWS Glue job Unit test case

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-glue, moto

I need help for writing python mock unit test case to trigger AWS Glue job using lambda. Please help me. Below is the sample code

```
# Set up logging
 import json
 import os
 import logging
 logger = logging.getLogger()
 logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

 # Import Boto 3 for AWS Glue
 import boto3
 client = boto3.client('glue')

 # Variables for the job: 
 glueJobName = "MyTestJob"

 # Define Lambda function
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
  logger.info('## TRIGGERED BY EVENT: ')

  logger.info(event['detail'])
  response = 
  client.start_job_run(JobName = glueJobName)
  logger.info('## STARTED GLUE JOB: ' + glueJobName)
  logger.info('## GLUE JOB RUN ID: ' + response['JobRunId'])
  return response
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you need to mock the client.start_job_run(JobName = glueJobName) or to trigger?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your test case look right now?

Comment: Yes @Farhad I need to mock client.start_job_run(JobName = glueJobName).

Answer (score 1):

Here's answer to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61480045/11305581

In short, you need mock low-level API response from boto3 client or use `moto` package if this functionality has been implemented there.

Comment: In moto package create job and start_job_run of AWS Glue functionality not implemented. https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/moto/glue/models.py . Please give some sample code to try for mock low level API response.

Comment: Could you please modify and share the snippet according to my code. Not able to understand from the snippet.